# php text parsing within each comma

Tags: php, parsing, text

I have the following text element stored within a text file. How could I use php and take the first content within each "" for the first and the following every 15 occurrences of "" and store them within a variable?

```
"Prairie Ridge","Prairie Ridge","WA","Washington","53053","Pierce","47.1443","-122.1408","","","1349.8","polygon","False","America/Los_Angeles","98360 98391","1840037882"
"Edison","Edison","WA","Washington","53057","Skagit","48.5602","-122.4311","","","127.4","polygon","False","America/Los_Angeles","98232","1840017314"
"Packwood","Packwood","WA","Washington","53041","Lewis","46.6085","-121.6702","","","213.9","polygon","False","America/Los_Angeles","98361","1840025265"
"Wautauga Beach","Wautauga Beach","WA","Washington","53035","Kitsap","47.5862","-122.5482","","","261.7","point","False","America/Los_Angeles","98366","1840037725"
"Harper","Harper","WA","Washington","53035","Kitsap","47.5207","-122.5196","","","342.1","point","False","America/Los_Angeles","98366","1840037659"
"Telma","Telma","WA","Washington","53007","Chelan","47.8432","-120.8157","","","1.4","point","False","America/Los_Angeles","98826","1840037825"
```

Comment: In a variable how? All in one variable each in its own? Show us an expected output.

Comment: for each $var echo $var